# sum of value based on a category

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to print the total sum of categories in every row using my-SQL and I am not able to do it can anyone please help me,

example:

| store | region | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 106 | Atlanta | 250000 |
| 107 | Atlanta | 300000 |
| 108 | New England | 100000 |
| 109 | New England | 150000 |
| 110 | New England | 270000 |

to convert it into a table like below

| store | region | sales | total sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | Atlanta | 200000 | 750000 |
| 106 | Atlanta | 250000 | 750000 |
| 107 | Atlanta | 300000 | 750000 |
| 108 | New England | 100000 | 520000 |
| 109 | New England | 150000 | 520000 |
| 110 | New England | 270000 | 520000 |

Comment: What does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth 8.0.22 is output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum` as a `window function`:

```
select *, 
Sum(sales) over (partition by region) as TotalSales
from table
```